# Does running rake asset:precompile always return the same filenames?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm dockerizing my rails app and thinking of moving the asset compilation out of the image build and into the container start command. This should be fine if I only have one container running, I'm worried if this will cause filename conflicts etc if I scale and spin up another container.

If I run the compilation twice with no code change will it output different file names?

Comment: that depends on the way the hash is calculated. in general, it shouldnt.

Answer (score 2):

Sprockets inserts a `SHA256` hash of the file content into the name. If the content does not change, hash will be the same.

Rails note on cash key: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care-questionmark
Sprockets method to generate digest: https://github.com/rails/sprockets/blob/master/lib/sprockets/digest_utils.rb#L91

Comment: Perfect! That was my assumption - but wanted to check. Thanks